# Ender 3 Pro - Randomly skip lines

Tags: print-quality, creality-ender-3, extrusion

I am a newbie to the 3D printing world. Every night spending hours researching and troubleshooting. Recently though I am having a weird problem for which I can not figure out a solution. While printing it randomly skips a line or two (see attached photo). I have an Ender 3 Pro that is about a month old. I have installed a glass bed on it and I am using silk white pla. I am printing with the following settings:

- 210 °C Nozzle temperature,
- Bed at 60 °C,
- Fan speed at 70 %,
- Print speed at 45 mm/s,
- layer height 0.2 mm with stock nozzle,
- 10 % cubic infill,
- and plate adhesion type is skirt.

Any help/advise would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Looks like extrusion issues... PLA? Then 210 °C is rather hot.

Comment: Are there any sounds like clicking or buzzing coming from the extruder? Is there a lot of dust building up in the extruder?

Comment: Can you post your first layer of G-code? Does the rendering show these gaps?

Comment: 210 is fine for PLA, and hotter shouldn't cause this sort of issue. I normally print it at 210 and 220 on some filament with layers 0.2 mm or larger.

Comment: Have you ever disassembled the bowden tube setup, especially at the hotend? Putting it back together wrong can cause this sort of issue.

Comment: I didn't hear any unusual sounds asides from the motors itself. There is a bit of residue from the filament by the extruder. I will clean that up and see if that makes any difference. 

The render doesn't show these gaps. This happened only in the first 2 layers, after that it printed the rest fine.  

I haven't disassembled the bowden tube or the hot end. 

I suspect that it has something to do with the extruder. i just can't figure out what is it. As i am writing this, I just realized that the one thing i haven't checked is the extruder  gear. Thanks everyone for sharing and commenting

Comment: Sorry for the late update. I am still struggling with this issue. The extruder gear was loose and was falling down, hence missing lines completely as the filament wasn't being fed. I tightened the screws and it resolved it for the most part. It is not as bad as the picture but it is still happening randomly. I have noticed though a few things. It only does it in the angle shown in the picture. Which makes me wonder if it has anything to do with the Y axis.

Comment: another thing that I have noticed is a loud clicking sound. It happens randomly and when it happens the extruder gear moves back. Not sure if this is normal. I have recorded a video of it. Hopefully ill be able to upload it. It is 5 seconds and the click happens at 3rd sec.  I have cleaned the nozzle and ensured that the filament flows properly. If anyone else has experienced this or has any thoughts then I would really appreciate it. Thank you all for taking time to read and comment.